# How to reset the state to null if the input is empty?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some inputs with a state set to `null` and when the end-user types something and delete all, the input came back to an empty string.
How can I set the state to get back to `null` ? 
I have a problem with the IF statement below who is not working when the user delete all his sentence. The state is `""` instead of `null`

Thanks for your help

```
onChange = (e, name, country) => {
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      this.setState({ [name]: { ...this.state[name], [country]: null } });
    }
    this.setState({ [name]: { ...this.state[name], [country]: e.target.value } });
  }
```

Comment: Your second setState instruction always gets executed because it is not contained in an ELSE condition

Comment: thanks that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make onChange method

```
onChange = (event, name, country) => {
   const { value } = event.target 
   this.setState({ 
       [name]: { ...this.state[name], [country]: value ? value : null } 
    });
}
```

When country value blank string set back it to `null`

Comment: Thanks a lot that's worked. Yes I forgot the else conditiion... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because after your IF statement this line will be executed

```
this.setState({ [name]: { ...this.state[name], [country]: e.target.value } });
```

Answer (score 1):

as @Stefan already said your second setState statement gets executed after the first if.

To shorten your code and make it work correctly you could use something along those lines:

```
onChange = (e, name, country) => {
this.setState({ [name]: { ...this.state[name], [country]: e.target.value ? this.target.value : null } });
```

this.target.value is false if value is "", undefined or null and true in all the other cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was the problem !! Thanks